# Prevent page rendering before data is returned

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxtjs and have a page that returns some data from a vuex store

```
created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('cases/loadcases');
  },
```

How do I get my page to wait until the data has been returned before rendering please?

Many Thanks

Comment: `<div v-if="cases.length"> ... your page ... </div>` if `cases` is an array and is in your `data` section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nuxt [asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/api/)/[fetch](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch) methods.
Here some example of page that will be loaded after 10 seconds:

```
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}
export default {
  async fetch({ store, redirect }) {
    await timeout(10000) // emulate long api call
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't. All you can is show some kind of loader (component), or simply not show the component during loading with v-if or v-show directive. That's all.